# Wordpress disable code editor formatting for a page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I have a wordpress page where I need to paste a block of html code, but when I output using `the_content()` you know that wp wraps things in `<p>` and so on, so I want for THAT PAGE to echo out the exact code that I paste in the editor without that auto formmating, is there a function or something, I've searched and found `wpautop`but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch from the WYSIWYG-View to the HTML-View by clicking the tab at top right corner of the editor window.

There you can inset your raw code surrounded by `<pre>` `</pre>` tags.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Note: I had to put the tags only around the problem area. Surrounding the entire code created odd gaps between each div.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want code that will execute, and not be seen, then you might try [stampede design](http://www.stampede-design.com/blog/2010/12/disable-html-auto-formatting-in-wordpress/)'s solution.

There is also a [raw HTML plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/) that might help.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.