# wordpress formatting.php - fix double dash

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, path, directory

I have a problem with wordpress, as it automatically transforms double "--" into a long dash. I found a quick fix for this as suggested in this short article:

- [Wordpress - Fix double dash problem](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2007/06/01/stop-wordpress-from-turning-double-dash-into-long-dash)

The only problem is, from my dashboard on wordpress online in my webbrowser, I couldn't figure out where/how to find the file wordpress/wp-includes/[formatting.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/formatting.php) which needs to be edited to solve the problem.

I also checked this other answers about wordpress, e.g.

- [how to modify date format in wordpress list comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350375/how-to-modify-date-format-in-wordpress-list-comments)
- [How to customize Date Format in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100483/how-to-customize-date-format-in-wordpress)
- [Wordpress disable code editor formatting for a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838789/wordpress-disable-code-editor-formatting-for-a-page)

But they don't mention anything about how/where to find the file wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php .

Any comments or suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't modify the WordPress core source code, this problem can be fixed by "adding" a plugin. This way you won't loose your fix when WordPress gets updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[code language="css"]
   // your code here
   if(correct)
   { puts("my wordpress text now shows the dash " -- " this is cool!");
   }
[/code]
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`--` is converted to an "en dash" by the core function `wptexturize()` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize)|[source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L73)). Here's a plugin to disable the feature: https://gist.github.com/toscho/982554

Comment: To use a plugin, you need to do your blog hosting it in a site server, customizing your dashboard. Plugin using wordpress directly from the browser is not possible. I am not working as blogger, will do it in my spare time only for simple posting. But thanks for the suggestion. In the the future if I decide to use a server to host my blog, then I would consider the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get access to the files on your server, then just follow the file path.  If you have cPanel, you can edit files directly, otherwise you'll probably need to setup an ftp client, like [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my case, I am using it directly on wordpress.com website. How to get into the file formatting.php?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't edit those files at all on wordpress.com, you need to either self host your site or look at wordpress.org